# Legend gets messy after saving plot as a PDF

Tags: r, plot

I have plotted several line graph.
But after saving my work into pdf file. The legend line runs>< whole graph become messy~~
can i know any ways to adjust it?

```
#test OF POOLED VARIANCE T TEST for  (100,100) GAMMA equal 
M <- c(1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3)
yt <- c(0.0509,0.0501,0.0487,0.0490,0.0510) 
yt1<-c(0.0493,0.0498,0.0547,0.0568,0.0580)
yt2<-c(0.0485,0.0513,0.0551,0.0556,0.0554)
yt3<-c(0.0518,0.0523,0.0588,0.0618,0.0625)
yt4<-c(0.0493,0.0552,0.0600,0.0607,0.0658)
plot(M, yt, type="l",col="green",xlab="Standard Deviation Ratio (SDR)", ylim = c(0.025, 0.145),
     ylab="Simulated Type I Error Rate",lwd=2)
abline(h=c(0.025,0.075),col=241,lty=3,lwd=2)

lines(M,yt1, lty=1,lwd=2,col="red")
lines(M,yt2,lty=1,lwd=2,col="purple4")
lines(M,yt3,lty=1,lwd=2,col="steelblue3")
lines(M,yt4, lty=1,lwd=2,col="gray27")

#test OF POOLED VARIANCE T TEST for  (10,10) GAMMA equal 
M <- c(1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3)
y <- c(0.0427,0.0529,0.0632,0.0672,0.0747) 
y1<-c(0.0421,0.0513,0.0714,0.0785,0.0920)
y2<-c(0.0422,0.0559,0.0767,0.0946,0.1063)
y3<-c(0.0346,0.0609,0.0873,0.1062,0.1248)
y4<-c(0.0334,0.0649,0.0988,0.1282,0.1433)
lines(M,y, lty=2,col="darkgreen",lwd=2)

lines(M,y1, lty=2,lwd=2,col="darkred")
lines(M,y2,lty=2,lwd=2,col="purple4")
lines(M,y3,lty=2,lwd=2,col="steelblue3")
lines(M,y4, lty=2,lwd=2,col="lightgoldenrod4")


legend("topleft",c("t(10,10,1.5)","t(10,10,2)",
"t(10,10,2.5)","t(10,10,3)","t(10,10,3.5)","t(100,100,1.5)","t(100,100,2)",
"t(100,100,2.5)","t(100,100,3)","t(100,100,3.5)"),
col=c("darkgreen","darkred","purple4","steelblue3","lightgoldenrod4","green","red","purple4",
"steelblue3","gray27"),lwd=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),lty=c(2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1),cex=0.77)
```

The output looks like the following [image]

As the figure shows, the legend messy. Can I know what can do to ensure that the lines do not run?

Comment: this is a part of my thesis work. After i inserting this R graph into word, then i save as pdf , but noticed that the graf turn out like the one shown in questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have plotted several line graph. But after saving my work into pdf file. The legend line runs>< whole graph become messy

This seems to say that your original output on R graphics window is fine. If you want to save your plot to pdf file, do not generate it on R graphics window first, then save it. You should plot it on a pdf file straight away. Use the following:

```
pdf("myplot.pdf")  ## open a pdf file for plotting
## ... your R code for plotting
dev.off()  ## close pdf; you must do this!
```

The output pdf is under your working directory. In case you don't know it, do `getwd()` in R, and you will see this path.

If you work with Microsoft Word, then you may try this instead:

```
jpeg("myplot.jpeg", quality = 100)  ## open a JPEG file for plotting; no quality loss
## ... your R code for plotting
dev.off()  ## close JPEG; you must do this!
```

This will output your plot as a JPEG. You can insert it into WORD, then convert it to pdf. You should not have problem again this way.

Comment: yup,tried it , it works.but the graph have a bit blur compare to original output from R><